# Group item from an array based on the date

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2017-11-01 09:15:02
            [Country] => France
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2017-11-01 04:45:01
            [Country] => Spain
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2017-11-03 04:45:01
            [Country] => Italy
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2017-11-04 04:45:01
            [Country] => Canada
        )
)
```

I need to group this array based on the date.

For example, countries with the same day (not hour) should be grouped together.

What I tried:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($array as $data) {
  $id = $data['Date'];
  if (isset($array[$Date])) {
     $array[$Date][] = $data;
  } else {
     $array[$Date] = array($data);
  }
}
```

Could you please help me finding what I missed ?

Thanks.

Comment: just set only date without hours as idex of arrray

Comment: Is the array result of DB query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the key to the date in only `Y-m-d` format or something that doesn't include the time.  Also, create a new array and don't add to the existing one:

```
foreach($array as $data) {
    $id = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['Date']));
    $result[$id][] = $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
foreach($array as $arr){
    $ex = explode(' ', $arr['Date']);//explode the dates via space and the first element will be the date like 2017-11-01
    $newarr[$ex[0]][] = $arr['Country'];
}
```

output is

```
Array
(
    [2017-11-01] => Array
        (
            [0] => France
            [1] => Spain
        )
    [2017-11-03] => Array
        (
            [0] => Italy
        )
    [2017-11-04] => Array
        (
            [0] => Canada
        )

)
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputArray = array();
foreach ($inputArray as $data) {
   if (isset($array[$Date])) {
      $outputArray[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['Date']))][] = $data;
   }else{
      $outputArray['notSet'][] = $data;
   }
}
```